# I responded to a even in Outlook, how do I get back to "no response"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have accepted occurring meeting in Outlook, but all of the people didn't respond to the invitation. How do I delete my response so I'm not declining the event but also I'm not the only one who accepted it?

Answer (score 3):

The "accept" email has gone and unlikely you can pull it back.

So now you have accepted, all you can do is delete your acceptance.

You can do this for one meeting or a string of meetings. It is for you and not for others. You can also send the decline to the organizer. It is quite flexible but those are the options. You cannot return to "no response" once the acceptance has been sent.

Ask the Meeting Owner to cancel and withdraw the meeting for everyone (not just you) and then it will go away properly.

If the meeting is "too" large, then you must deal with your own invites just for yourself and do not send your response. That works.

That is how Outlook Invites work.

I have done dozens and dozens of meetings this way.

==============

**Instructions to manage invites:** (apologies to spikey_ritchie for some overlap)

For any Outlook Calendar Event, right click on it to (say) delete.

A dialogue window comes up.
We are talking about Delete, so expand the Delete Menu.

The next menu tells you that you can deal with the (1) Occurrence or the (2) Series - that is, one invite or all in a Series.

For each choice (Occurrence or Series) you have 3 options:

Edit response before sending ("I am away that day and must cancel").

Send the response now (just send the delete (decline) response back to meeting owner with no explanation).

**Do not send response**  (this is probably what you want to "return to no response" .  The invite will be deleted from your calendar and is now "divorced" from the owner's calendar.

I do this when "owner" sends out a series (all same date including holidays and vacations).  I just delete the invite when I will be away and do not send a response. Why? "owner" already knows I will be on vacation. Meeting occurs (or does not occur) and I do not show up.

The reasoning is yours but Outlook can be managed to delete invites in your Outlook without sending response back.

That is the best you can do once invites have originally been issued and accepted and the circumstances change.

I have provided a screen shot to assist you.

[image]

Comment: I have the "accept" meeting at hand, it was sent, can I do something about it if I have it? Meeting is huge 100+, so withdrawing meeting for everyone won't be possible

Comment: You can delete your own Invites for yourself for a meeting or a string of meetings and not affect anyone else. Otherwise the organizer needs to delete.

Comment: I made just I covered everything. If the meeting is "too" large to withdraw, you must deal with your own invites (delete for example) and do not send response back to organizer. Outlook is flexible enough to allow you to manage your own calendar.

Comment: John, could you please send me some sort of tutorial on how to do this? So how do I manage it right now? Should I cancel the even and not send the response to the owner, and then ask for another invitation?

Comment: I have made a significant improvement to my answer including a screen shot to help you. Yes, cancel the event and do not send a response. It is up to you about asking for another invitation but you can do that.

Comment: Thanks John, so deleting the invitation without sending a response makes sense. Would that delete me from the list, so I won't be that one person who accepted it, then I can ask to be re-invited. Right? :)
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Remember that this is as much a business thing as an Outlook thing. Outlook just enables things. And yes just ask  to be re-invited. My steps are general and then you adapt to your business needs.

Comment: By the way, re-reading, Outlook does not delete you from the lists. Again that is a business thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your `Accept` to `Decline`, simply find the event in your calendar, right-click it and change your response to `Decline`.

[image]

You can't withdraw your original response, only change it to something else.

Comment: Completely agree. You can't withdraw your original response.